# Is it possible to prevent device from destroying my android app on reboot?

Tags: android, boot

I am making an android app. In this app I am trying to save my app from destroying on reboot or factory reset. can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "save my app" means.

Answer (score 1):

Apps won't get deleted if you reboot the device. About the second part(factory reset), the whole point of a factory reset is that everything on the phone will be deleted and restored to factory settings. If you want to keep your app even after that you'd have to install your own OS with the app installed as a part of it.

Also, if a reboot is somehow "destroying the app", something is very wrong with the app and you need to find out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean by "Save my app" that the app `.apk` should be still present and installed, thats impossible for a **factory reset**, like the name suggest its a `reset`.

If you want to save the settings of the app prior to rebooting, you can do that with a `background service`, which can be also called when the phone finishes the reboot.